# Formal Languages: Trouble understanding powers

Tags: formal-languages

I've run into an argument with some peers about how to perform power operations on languages.

```
                               Say: A = {2,00}
```

At first myself and my peers were all in agreement that say for instance A^3 would output:

```
                       A = AAA = {(2,00),(2,00),(2,00)}
```

Likewise A^2:

```
                           A = AA = {(2,00),(2,00)}
```

However a fellow SO member said that this was not the case? ANd that say for instance A^3 would contain 8 elements?

Could anyone shed any light on who's right? And more importantly why?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are two languages, then $AB$ is the set of all strings $ab$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Thus $AB$ has $|A|\cdot|B|$ elements, where $|A|$ denotes the number of elements of $A$. Now $A^2=AA$ by definition, and $A^3=A^2A$ an so forth. So in your case, $A^2=\{22,200,002,0000\}$. Now I'll leave $A^3$ to you.

Comment: So would A^3 = {222,220,200,000,002,022,202,020)? Thank you for your time, I appreciate it

Comment: Yes, except you'd have to double the zeros in each string, since $A$ a double zero in it (and no single zero).

Comment: My friend says he thinks i'm looking at language concatenation rather than string concatenation... Would string concatenation result in my first answer?

Comment: @Fendorio To be honest, I'm completely baffled about what your first answer could possibly mean.  How do the $()$ signs suddenly appear from nowhere, and what are they supposed to indicate?  What strings actually belong to this language?